Is there an ARM Thumb-1 instruction that will zero a register without affecting the flags?
I'm trying to find a single ARM Thumb-1 instruction to zero a register, but not change the flags. I've considered the following:
MOVS R1, #0
EORS R1, R1
SUBS R1, R1

but they each affect the flags. Any suggestions?

LDR and POP do not set the flags AFAIK, nor does a MOV between a low and high register. But those would all be pretty inconveient to use for zeroing a register I suppose.

you could load zero from a nearby pool.

In order to fit all instructions in 16 bits, thumb1 made many compromises.  One is that instruction affect the condition code (removal of 'S' bit set to zero).  Others are r0-r7 limitation for many instructions, no conditional execution and two register ISA.  You won't find a solution without additional limitations to MOV Rx, #0 as in ARM32.  Ie, you will need some dedicated register, memory, slower execution, etc.
